# Read_Excel with list of list for usecols

Tags: python, pandas

I have to read several Excel files(from a url link) that contain a fixated 5 columns. However the name of the columns may slightly diverge i.e('foo','fo','f(0)') because people.

There is a way that I can pass a list of lists containing, `like [['foo','fo','f(0)'],['foo2','f02','f(o)2'],...]` for usecols?

Now I use this code:

```
links = df['column_I_need'].str.join(sep='')
col_names = ['foo','fo','f(0)']
for i in links:
    try:
        name = i[50:]
        df = pd.read_excel(i, header = 1, names = col_names, encoding = 'utf-8') #usecols = names)
        file_name = r"%s\%s" %(pasta_sol,name)

        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name , engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, header = True, index = True)
        writer.close()

    except (TypeError, IndexError, ValueError, XLRDError, BadZipFile, urllib.error.URLError) as e:
        erros.append((i, e.args[0]))
```

The information regarding each column in each file is for a specific field in the system.

I really couldn't find anything. In most of the files the value in the cells are correct, but people change the column name.

If someone have any idea I would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: been in this situation many a time, I can't find the function I wrote, but what I did was create a single object of all the excel files in a dictionary, I then read each file with only 1 row to extract all the column names and then created a list per each key (your excel file) that matched my string matching critereon, then whilst reading each excel file I used each keys matched_cols list. I'll have a look to see if I can find it, if not I think you seem competent enough to write your own :)

Comment: @Datanovice Thanks for asnwering. I will try to build up this code. If you find yours would be of great help. If I'm successful I will put up an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the rough version of the function I used in my last role (I wasn't up to scratch with Git and didn't version control/save all my stuff)

What this will do is iterate over your chosen directory and return a list of matching excel files with their path and the column.

When the returned dictionary, you can loop over the filepaths and use the value as the usecols argument.

```
for path,column in return_value.items():
    df = pd.read_excel(path,usecols=column)
```

## In Action.

```
return_value = find_common_column(r"C:\Users\datanovice\Documents\Python Scripts\Test"
,sheetname='Sheet1'
,col_list=['dat','test'])

print(return_value)

{WindowsPath('C:/Users/datanovice/Documents/Python Scripts/Test/doc_1.xlsx'): Index(['data'], dtype='object')}
```

## Modules

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy 
from pathlib import Path
from xlrd import XLRDError
```

## Function

```
def find_common_column(path,sheetname,col_list=list):
    """
    Takes in three arguments and returns a 
    dictionary of paths and common columns

    Path : Path to your excel files.  
    sheetname : the sheet we will use. 
    collist : columns you need to parse from each sheet.
    """
    excel_dict = {f : pd.ExcelFile(f) for f in Path(path).glob('*.xlsx')}

    pat = '|'.join(col_list)

    dfs = {}
    for filename,each_excel in excel_dict.items():
        try:
            df = pd.read_excel(each_excel,sheet_name=sheetname,nrows=1)
            cols = df.filter(regex=pat,axis=1).columns
            dfs[filename] = cols

        except XLRDError as err:
            pass
    return dfs
```